# When using a Jenkins pipeline, is there a way to get the user that responded to an input() action?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Consider the following example

```
node {
    stage('Build') {
        echo "do buildy things"
    }

    stage('Deploy') {
        hipchatSend(
            color: "PURPLE",
            message: "Holding for deployment authorization: ${env.JOB_NAME}, job ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}. Authorize or cancel at ${env.BUILD_URL}",
        )
        input('Push to prod?') //Block here until okayed.
        echo "Deployment authorized by ${some.hypothetical.env.var}"
        echo "do deploy things"
     }
}
```

When responding to the input, the user name that clicked the button is stored in the build log.

Is this username made available in a variable that I could use in, say, another hipChatSend?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Supply the field `submitterParameter` to `input`:

```
def userName = input message: '', submitterParameter: 'USER'
echo "Accepted by ${userName}"
```

The value of `submitterParameter` doesn't matter if you doesn't have any parameters. But if you have parameters, then it will specify the name of the array element which holds the value:

```
def ret = input message: '', parameters: [string(defaultValue: '', description: '', name: 'para1')], submitterParameter: 'USER'
echo "Accepted by ${ret['USER']}"
```